# Check a checkbox based on other cell value, but still allow boxes to be manually checked

Tags: google-sheets, checkbox

I am working on a Google Sheet Checklist with multiple sections.

I have two columns in my checklist. Column A is Complete, Complete B is N/A.

I have header columns in each section that has a checkbox if the section is not applicable.

I have a current formula in Column B that states =IF('Column B Header Cell'=TRUE,TRUE,FALSE).

My problem is that there are sections that need to be complete but may have some questions that are N/A.

With the formula above it does not allow them to also be manually checked. Is there a way to do this?

I can just erase the formula and paste FALSE, but not all of my employee are familiar enough to know to do that.

Comment: Please include a text based example, such as sharing an editable sheet. Please ensure that your example represents your needs accurately and includes your desired outputs coded manually.